# Is it not proper to use the send method to return HTML? Express

Tags: html, express, rendering, response, router

I am playing with express, in the past I have used echo with PHP to render out lines of html. In node/express I can add html to a variable and use res.send to return html. That way I can run loops and other things right in the function returning that route. Is this method bad practice? Below I have an example that counts to four.

```
var router = express.Router();
let a = (req, res, next) => {
  let send = `<html>`;
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    send += `${i}`;
  }
  send += `</html>`;
  res.send(send);
  //res.download(filepath)
}
router.get('/', [a]);
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I think you want to look into the topic of how to use template engines with express.
e.g.: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-express-template-engines

Comment: Thanks I have and started looking at ejs, I can do either way I guess. I am trying to find out if this method is disliked for being untraditional. I know it works, it is an industry yes or no question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a way to go about express router but it's probably not the easiest and it would cause a lot of code on your router page. It all depends on how large and scalable you want your project to be. If you are looking at doing a smaller project then this would work but if you were doing something a little larger e.g. e-commerce site then I would say put your html files in a separate folder and create a views directory for express. I would also suggest using an open source JavaScript Framework such as ReactJS, Vue, or ejs to name a few. You would have to do more code to your express server by adding views as seen in this link
[Adding views in express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

So instead of sending the html you would do something like res.render('/home'); if that is what you called your home page in your views file.

If that didn't answer your question please let me know.